# Why does pgfplots use a left handed co-ordinate system, and how can I adapt it?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, 3d

I just noticed that `pgfplots` uses a [left-handed co-ordinate system](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Left-HandedCoordinateSystem.html) when plotting in 3D:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest,compat/show suggested version=false}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=10cm,y=10cm]

        %New Axis
        \begin{axis}[
        view = {-15}{-25},
        axis lines = middle,
        xtick = \empty, ytick = \empty, ztick = \empty,
        xlabel = $x$, ylabel = $y$, zlabel = $z$,
        declare function = {
            xc(\t) = \t*cos(\t);
            yc(\t) = \t*sin(\t);
            zc(\t) = \t;
        }]

            %Create Conical Spiral
            \addplot3[domain = 0:460, samples = 200, samples y = 0, mark = none]
            ( {xc(x)},{yc(x)},{zc(x)});

            \def\param{420}

            %Add Point
            \addplot3[mark options = {color=black,scale=0.5},mark = *]
            coordinates {({xc(\param)},{yc(\param)}, {zc(\param)})};

            % Line to Point
            \addplot3[dashed] coordinates {
            ({xc(\param)}, {0}, {0})
            ({xc(\param)}, {yc(\param)}, {0})
            ({xc(\param)}, {yc(\param)}, {zc(\param)})
            };

            % Line to Point
            \addplot3[dashed] coordinates {
            ({0}, {yc(\param)}, {0})
            ({xc(\param)}, {yc(\param)}, {0})
            (0,0,0)
            };

        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Conventionally in physics and engineering, we use right handed co-ordinate systems.  I know the dummy fix is to swap the `xlabel` and `ylabel`. Unfortunately this means I need to switch all the x and y co-ordinates to have everything drawing the way I want it to, and conciously entering `(yc,xc,zc)` is just confusing.

Why does pgfplots do this? And more importantly, is there a creative way around this issue so that I can enter values using a right-handed co-ordinate system?

Comment: `y post scale=-1`?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Yup... that's it. Do you want to create an answer or shall I?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I cannot answer the "why", but the easiest way of getting a right-hand coordinate system is to add

```
y post scale=-1
```

to the `axis` options, which essentially flips the y-axis around.